# Can Capybara play nice with Turbolinks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm getting random failures when using turbolinks with capybara. For example, even though the page loads (as I can see it in the browser, the capybara screenshot and the generated output) it can't seem to find my dom node.

If on the other hand I disable the turbolink option on my link, everything works fine.

Any clues/tips?

Thanks

Comment: If you write your tests and expectations correctly ( allowing for capybaras waiting behavior) then turbolinks should not cause issues - add an example of the test and failure you're getting and we can give pointers

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing, and I assume it's because of Turbolinks' page replacement strategy mixed with either caching or too-fast lookup on Capybara's side. I think it's almost obvious you'd have intermittent failures if you know how they both work, was hoping someone had a solution...

Comment: I am having the same trouble, looks like I need to allow for the waiting behavour or somehow disable turbolinks whilst running tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try change default value of `Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5`

Answer (score -1):

Use `js:true`. Example:

```
describe "Some feature", js: true do
 ...
end
```

Comment: Without js: true turbolinks just wouldn't be used, so its pretty clear the OP is already using a JS enabled driver for the test